# Как реализовать binding нажатия кнопки в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Добрый вечер.

Как можно реализовать нажатие кнопки в строке `DataGrid` по патерну MVVM? Есть `View` с `DataGrid` в которую передали свойство `ObservableCollection<Layer>` образующие строки имеет соответственно кнопку, для изменения одного из свойств экземпляра объекта `Layer`.
В `ViewMoedel` имеет свойство

```
public MainViewModel()
{
     ClickCommandLayerColorSelection = new Command( arg =>
     {
     //выполнение кода после нажатия
     ColorSelection colorSelection = new ColorSelection();             
     colorSelection.DataContext = new ColorSelectionViewModel(); 
     colorSelection.ShowDialog();
     });
}    

public ICommand ClickCommandLayerColorSelection{get;set;}
```

XAML View выглядит так.

```
<!--  Отображение в Таблице свойста слоев  -->
        <DataGrid
            Name="Layers"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            CanUserResizeRows="False"
            HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFE4DDDD"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LayersCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLayer}"
            VerticalGridLinesBrush="#00000000">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="*"
                    Binding="{Binding NameLayer, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Header="Название слоя" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn
                    Width="auto"
                    Binding="{Binding ShowLayer, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Header="Выкл" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto" Header="Цвет">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button
                                Width="17"
                                Height="17"
<!-- Как правильно привязать свойство? То что представлено ниже используется 
вроде для MVVM-light который я не использую в проекте -->
<!-- Решение надо было изменить path=DataContext.ClickCommandLayerColorSelection 
а так же AncestorType={x:Type DataContext} и тогда все заработает--> 
                                Command="{Binding Path=DataContext, 
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                             AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate>
                                                    <Rectangle
                                                        Name="ColorLayer"
                                                        Width="17"
                                                        Height="17"
                                                        Fill="{Binding ColorLayer, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                        Stroke="Black" />
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: В привязке команды замените `DataContext` на `DataContext.ClickCommandLayerColorSelection`

Comment: @Андрей  Ошибка "Не может разрешить свойство `ClickCommandLayerColorSelection` в контексте данных типа "object".

Comment: @Андрей Получается что свойство не тот формат пытается поймать?

Comment: Вы своей странице DataContext установили?

Comment: попробуйте так - `Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ClickCommandLayerColorSelection, 
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                             AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}`

Comment: @KJfe: Если у вас появился ответ, то опубликуйте его не в вопросе, а отдельным ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как говорил @Андрей и @Foggy Finder необходимо было определить в binding параметры `AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}` и `Path=DataContext.ClickCommandLayerColorSelection`
В результате получается:

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ClickCommandLayerColorSelection, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}
```

В результате свойство ClickCommandLayerColorSelection ловит изменения и обрабатывает его в mainViewModel, а там уже творим с этим событием что хотим.